# VBA is changing my dates to mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm when importing

Tags: vba, excel, date, datetime

So I am importing dates from a computer generated CSV file. In the CSV file, the dates are in the dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm format. However when I import it using VBA, VBA reads it as mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm. so VBA reads 01/05/2015 (1st of may) as 5th of jan.

I checked, and the CSV file is definietly in the dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm format.

any help in fixing this would be greatly appreciated.

So when I open the CSV file manually, the date is in the dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm format. Like 1st of december 2016 would be 01/12/2016 1:00. But when VBA opens it, it changes to 12/01/2016 1:00.

This is the entire code in question. Its nothing complex, and I cant figure out whats wrong with it.

```
Sub import()
    Dim calbook As Workbook
    Dim newwb As Workbook
    Dim destiwb As Workbook
    Dim directory As String
    Dim Filename As String
    directory = "C:\Users\winterco\Desktop\"
    Set calbook = Workbooks("Data_totaliser1.xlsm")
    Filename = Dir(directory & "*.CSV")
    Set newwb = Workbooks.Add
    Set destiwb = ActiveWorkbook
    Do While Filename <> ""
        Workbooks.OpenText (directory & Filename)
        Call Sort_Data(Filename, destiwb, directory, calbook)
        Filename = Dir()  
    Loop  
End Sub
```

Comment: Under Format Cells --> Number --> Date  change the Locale to English (United Kingdom)

Comment: Hello! Thank you for responding. The CSV files are computer generated. I checked, and the date format is already set to English(New Zealand).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify all of the format details, Excel uses the most recently used `Text to Columns` settings when opening text files.

If you're using the `Workbooks.OpenText` method (instead of `Workbooks.Open` method), you can specify all of those formats. Try recording a macro while opening a text file, to see how the formats are specified.

One of the formats you can provide is the order of Day, Month and Year. If you can't find a format that works, you can define that column as `Text`, and then parse the data using formulas in a subsequent process.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response! So upon closer inspection, when I open the CSV file manually, the date is in the dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm format. But when VBA opens it, its somehow swaps the date and month around. For instance, when I open it manually, an example date would be 01/12/2016 1:00. When VBA opens it, the date becomes 12/01/2016 1:00. I'm not doing anything complex. I used `Workbooks.Open (directory & Filename)` where the directory and filename are defined above. I've been trying to use `.OpenText` but it still does the same thing.

Comment: You have to specify all of the settings when you use `OpenText`, and you cant specify the settings with `Open`, so just use `OpenText` with all of the settings specified.

Comment: Record a macro while opening manually, and you should get all of the settings recorded. Then just copy/paste as appropriate.

Comment: So when I record a macro to open it, it simply does `workbooks.open`, and the dates are correct. However, when I copy that exact macro to my code, it opens the file and the dates are somehow muddled up again. Forgive the silly question, but how do i record a macro to do a `.OpenText`?

Comment: You need to use `Data..From Text..` ribbon command, not the usual `File..Open..` ribbon command. Or maybe you are using Office 2007 (macro recording was useless in that). Maybe, try temporarily changing the file suffix to `.txt` and the recorder might use the `OpenText` method.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! I actually found a really simple solution and thought I'd share. The problem is apparently that `.Open` doesnt recognize any other "time" format than american. so add `local:=true` to your code, like this `Workbooks.Open (directory & Filename), local:=True` and boom, problem solved

Answer (score 0):

It's a real nightmare... I never found a "simple" solution.

My workaround is that I always open CSV with VBA as strings to do the conversions myself, this way I don't have bad surprises. Or if you want to make it less work, do as Thunderframe suggested, open as text, this way no conversion, and do a loop with the code here under:

```
Dim z: z = VBA.Split(VBA.Replace(x, "-", "/"), "/") 'works with 01/01/2001 and 01-01-2001
answer = DateSerial(Left(z(2), 4), z(1), Left(z(0), 2)) 'left for the case DD/MM/YY 00:00:00, because unlike you I don't give a f* for time of day. If you want the time of the day, you'll need to use :

z=split(x,":")
answer =answer + TimeSerial(right(z(0),2)  , z(1), z(2) ) 'untested code
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! I actually found a really simple solution and thought I'd share. The problem is apparently that `.Open` doesnt recognize any other "time" format than american. so add `local:=true` to your code, like this `Workbooks.Open (directory & Filename), local:=True` and boom, problem solved!